# Struts2 - First Steps - My page doesnt get the right css

Tags: struts2

Hi making my first page using Struts2.

This is the easy code :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/interfaccia.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/links.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/profile.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/affitta.css" />

        <title>
                Struts2 - The Sinfonet Portal
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <s:div cssStyle="contenitore">
            <s:div cssStyle="header">
                <s:div cssStyle="header1">
                    <img src="img/logosw.png" alt="Logo Sinfonet" />
                </s:div>

                <s:div cssStyle="header2">
                    <img src="img/band1.jpg" alt="Flag 1" class="photoband" />
                    <img src="img/band2.jpg" alt="Flag 2" class="photoband" />
                    <img src="img/band3.jpg" alt="Flag 3" class="photoband" />
                </s:div>
            </s:div>

            <s:div cssStyle="center">
                <s:div cssStyle="menu">
                    <s:div cssStyle="menu_table">
                        <s:label cssStyle="menu_title" value="Login" />
                        <s:label cssStyle="menu_span" value="Username" />
                        <s:textfield />
                        <s:label cssStyle="menu_span" value="Password" />
                        <s:textfield />
                    </s:div>
                </s:div>
            </s:div>
        </s:div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I don't know why it doesnt get the right CSS style (in fact the page looks strange).

What am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that all of your CSS files are served properly (i.e., they aren't resulting in 404 errors)?

Comment: Ohhhh... i confused cssClass with cssStyle:) Ok...nice one!

Comment: +1 cssStyle is something diff den cssClass in tags implimentation

Answer (score 1):

You could try out your page with `<div` instead of `<s:div` and see what you get.

Comment: Agreed. You're probably best off sticking with standard HTML for a div. I'm not even sure why Struts2 has its own div tag.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a same problem, after parsing through struts css seem to vanish.

Solution: Just add folder name before style in href.

e.g:

Before:

```
href="style.css"
```

After:

```
href="foldername/style.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be nothing Struts2-specific. As Steven answered, check that you get the css-files served if you enter the URL they should be at directly. If not, it may be that you'll have to take a look in your WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml file if you're directing the requests wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<link href="<s:url value="css/interfaccia.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Then the Problem is not with the struts2 do one more thing when the page get displayed see its source and try to check if the css files are really accessible

Answer (score 0):

You Have to mention the whole path in every page

like..

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=**"<s:url value="/css/style.css"** />" />

for images

<img id="logo" src="<s:url value="/images/logo.png" />"  />